# REST: Acceptable number of records to return?

Tags: api, rest, rpc, api-design

I've read somewhere that you shouldn't return all records at once in a `GET` request and you should use some sort of pagination instead (e.g., `GET /users` shouldn't return all records specially if the record has millions of rows).

This is probably an arbitrary number but what is an acceptable or "standard" number of maximum records to return per `GET` request of records.

Comment: This is absolutely dependent on your application, use cases, data size, and many other factors. I often see default page sizes of 20 or so, for something like a simple user object that maybe contains a few small text fields, but this is an extremely broad question.